# Android social signin Quickblox chat

Tags: android, api, quickblox

Here is my code. I have read the quickblox docs and downloaded the samples. I don't understand why this is not working!!

I have the access token and I pass it to quickblox to sign in which it does (i can see it in the dashboard) but it does not sign me into chat instead a I received a big error saying that chat wasn't signed into.

Please please help. The code examples on the site are fine but I'm sure I am just placing something in the wrong place or have left something out. I am at the end of my tether!!

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

private String accessToken;
private String accessTokenSecret;

private QBUser user;
private SmackAndroid smackAndroid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toast.makeText(this,"this is the login part", 3000).show();
}
    smackAndroid = SmackAndroid.init(this);

    // get stored AccessToken in shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    accessToken = settings.getString( "twitter_access_token", null );
    accessTokenSecret = settings.getString( "twitter_access_token_secret", null );

    //AccessToken access_token = new AccessToken(accessToken,accessTokenSecret);

    //String TwitToken = String.valueOf(access_token);



    // have to start session and pass session ID
    String TwitToken = accessToken;
    String TwitTokenS = accessTokenSecret;
    QBUsers.signInUsingSocialProvider(QBProvider.TWITTER, TwitToken, TwitTokenS, new QBCallbackImpl(){

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Result result){
            if(result.isSuccess()){
                //QBUserResult qbUserResult = (QBUserResult) result;

                QBUser qbUser = ((QBUserResult)result).getUser();
                qbUser.setPassword(BaseService.getBaseService().getToken());
                QBChatService.getInstance().signIn(qbUser);
                //QBUsers.signIn(qbUser, null);

                //loginToChat(qbUser);
                Log.d("LogIn was successful","user: " + qbUser.toString());

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }else{
                Log.e("QB didn't login with Twitter",result.getErrors().toString()); 
            }
        }
    });
}

 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
        finish();
    }
 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        smackAndroid.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
 //  @Override
 //     public void onComplete(Result result, Object context) {
 //     } 

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Android SDK do you use?
Please download latest version here http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#Framework_changelog:

Did you check this Android Chat guide?
http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample

To login to chat you have to use this method:

```
QBUser qbUser = ((QBUserResult)result).getUser();
qbUser.setPassword(BaseService.getBaseService().getToken());

Log.d(TAG, "user: " + qbUser);

QBChatService.getInstance().loginWithUser(qbUser, LoginActivity.this);

@Override
public void onLoginSuccess() {
    Log.d(TAG, "success when login");
}

@Override
public void onLoginError(String error) {
    Log.e(TAG, "error when login");
}
```

What do you see in logs?

Comment: I am using the latest android sdk kitkat + google api's. I went through all the chat examples on site.

Comment: This is definitely for signInWithSocialProvider with chat ?

Comment: Hi tried that didn't work I am now getting a package error that app can't be found. However it is completely referenced correctly. I had this running as the example chat app with email sign in and i just wanted to convert it to the SocialProvider instead.

Comment: This is correct code for SocialProvider. 
please share your logs/errors

Comment: @Igor Khomenko If you are using loginWithUser() for social media login then what's the use of QBUsers.signInUsingSocialProvider() .

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is my LoginActivity.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements QBCallback {

    protected static final String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String accessToken;
    private String accessTokenSecret;

    private QBUser user;
    private SmackAndroid smackAndroid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Toast.makeText(this,"this is the login part", 3000).show();

        smackAndroid = SmackAndroid.init(this);

        // get stored AccessToken in shared Preferences
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        accessToken = settings.getString( "twitter_access_token", null );
        accessTokenSecret = settings.getString( "twitter_access_token_secret", null );

        //AccessToken access_token = new AccessToken(accessToken,accessTokenSecret);

        //String TwitToken = String.valueOf(access_token);



        // have to start session and pass session ID
        String TwitToken = accessToken;
        String TwitTokenS = accessTokenSecret;

            QBUsers.signInUsingSocialProvider(QBProvider.TWITTER,TwitToken,TwitTokenS,new QBCallbackImpl(),getApplicationContext());

        }   


    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result){
        if(result.isSuccess()){

            QBSessionResult res = (QBSessionResult)result;
            QBUser qbUser = ((QBUserResult)result).getUser();
            try {
                qbUser.setPassword(BaseService.getBaseService().getToken());
            } catch (BaseServiceException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //
            QBChatService.getInstance().loginWithUser(qbUser, new SessionCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLoginSuccess(){
//                  Intent intent = new Intent();
//                  
                    Intent intentChat = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK,intentChat);
                    startActivity(intentChat);
                    finish();
                    }
                @Override
                public void onLoginError(String error){
                    Log.i(TAG, "error when login"); 
                }
                });
            }
        }
     @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
            finish();
        }
     @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            smackAndroid.onDestroy();
            super.onDestroy();
        }
     @Override
        public void onComplete(Result result, Object context) {
        } 

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

And this is my chatActivity

```
public class ChatActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_MODE = "mode";
    private static final String TAG = ChatActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private EditText messageEditText;
    private Mode mode = Mode.SINGLE;
    private Chat chat;
    private ChatAdapter adapter;
    private ListView messagesContainer;

    public static void start(Context context, Bundle bundle) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        initViews();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        try {
            chat.release();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to release chat", e);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        messagesContainer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messagesContainer);
        messageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEdit);
        Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chatSendButton);
        TextView meLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meLabel);
        TextView companionLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.companionLabel);
        RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

        adapter = new ChatAdapter(this, new ArrayList<ChatMessage>());
        messagesContainer.setAdapter(adapter);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mode = (Mode) intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_MODE);
        switch (mode) {
            case GROUP:
                //chat = new RoomChat(this);
                container.removeView(meLabel);
                container.removeView(companionLabel);
                break;
            case SINGLE:
                chat = new SingleChat(this);
                int userId = intent.getIntExtra(SingleChat.EXTRA_USER_ID, 0);
                companionLabel.setText("user(id" + userId + ")");
                restoreMessagesFromHistory(userId);
                break;
        }

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String lastMsg = messageEditText.getText().toString();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(lastMsg)) {
                    return;
                }

                messageEditText.setText("");
                try {
                    chat.sendMessage(lastMsg);
                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "failed to send a message", e);
                }

                if (mode == Mode.SINGLE) {
                    showMessage(new ChatMessage(lastMsg, Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), false));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void showMessage(ChatMessage message) {
        saveMessageToHistory(message);
        adapter.add(message);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        scrollDown();
    }

    public void showMessage(List<ChatMessage> messages) {
        adapter.add(messages);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        scrollDown();
    }

    private void saveMessageToHistory(ChatMessage message) {
        if (mode == Mode.SINGLE) {
            ((App)getApplication()).addMessage(getIntent().getIntExtra(SingleChat.EXTRA_USER_ID, 0), message);
        }
    }

    private void restoreMessagesFromHistory(int userId) {
        List<ChatMessage> messages = ((App)getApplication()).getMessages(userId);
        if (messages != null) {
            showMessage(messages);
        }
    }

    private void scrollDown() {
        messagesContainer.setSelection(messagesContainer.getCount() - 1);
    }

    public static enum Mode {SINGLE, GROUP}
}
```

I'm no longer receiving an error however after login activity in does not open chatActivity.
I thought the flow of the sample app went splash --> main --> login/registration --> Chat??